# Can javascript filter by "style" values for an already filtered list of <li> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have an online store product page that shows a product image on the left and has some options (size, color) on the right. Now, when a customer lands on this page some of the color options are hidden using some javascript code. That code works like a champ. Now after the colors have been hidden, I need to have some other code select the first visible color option so that the page's other javascript code will load a correctly colored photo of the image. So, here is the HTML code that I am working with:

```
<div class="productOptionPickListSwatch">
<ul>
    <li style="display: none;" class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour selectedValue">
        <label for="1cd2d5722d58b184b22e60490cb790ad">
            <span class="previewContent">
                <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Ash Grey">
                    <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#D2D4D3;">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        <input checked="checked" class="validation" name="attribute[3091]" value="2704" id="1cd2d5722d58b184b22e60490cb790ad" type="radio">
        <span class="name">Ash Grey</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;" class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour">
        <label for="2ea2a6a1b415e9231d477cea8be09068">
            <span class="previewContent">
                <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Black">
                    <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#252525;">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        <input class="validation" name="attribute[3091]" value="2708" id="2ea2a6a1b415e9231d477cea8be09068" type="radio">
        <span class="name">Black</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;" class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour">
        <label for="702b2730a02e931fb60b8b032ca421f1">
            <span class="previewContent">
                <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Hunter Green">
                    <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#0D2C26;">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <input class="validation" name="attribute[3091]" value="2731" id="702b2730a02e931fb60b8b032ca421f1" type="radio">
            <span class="name">Hunter Green</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;" class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour">
        <label for="ab898f9ee27d5fba28b277b895f916f2">
            <span class="previewContent">
                <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Red">
                    <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#C01E36;">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <input class="validation" name="attribute[3091]" value="2766" id="ab898f9ee27d5fba28b277b895f916f2" type="radio">
            <span class="name">Red</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: inline-block;" class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour">
        <label for="237a97b716a4fec4ee62438c27e20570">
            <span class="previewContent">
                <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Wine">
                    <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#602B35;">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <input class="validation" name="attribute[3091]" value="2783" id="237a97b716a4fec4ee62438c27e20570" type="radio">
            <span class="name">Wine</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I did not create the HTML code above, some system did. But as you can see, some of the < li > tags have a style="display: none;" (the hidden color options) and there are two that have style="display: inline-block;" (the available color options).

What I want to be able to do is filter only the < li> tags that have a "style" that is equal to "inline-block" then once the first one is found, change its class to have "selectedValue" added and set input "checked=checked". My javascript code below works but sets the first < li> tag regardless of what the style is set to.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about').addClass('expand');
    $(".productOptionPickListSwatch ul").each(function(){
    $(this).children("li").first().addClass("selectedValue");
    $("li.selectedValue input.validation").attr('checked',true);

    });
    });
</script>
```

So, is this type of filter possible? Where does it go? What am I missing?

Thanks for any input.

**UPDATE________**

So, I used the code supplied by @dtanders which works based on the code provided in my initial request. But when the code was tested on the actual page, nothing happened. As stated in one of my comments below, there is some javascript that is filtering the swatches and adding the "style" info to the < li> tags. I found that code:

```
for (var j=0; j < colorArray.length; j++){
    console.log(colorArray[j]);
     $('.productOptionPickListSwatch span[title="'+ colorArray[j] + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'inline-block');
  }
```

I then added @dtanders supplied code to it:

```
for (var j=0; j < colorArray.length; j++){
    console.log('colorArray: ' + colorArray[j]);
    console.log('colorArray_J: ' + j);
     $('.productOptionPickListSwatch span[title="'+ colorArray[j] + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'inline-block')
                     .first().addClass("selectedValue")
     .find("input.validation").prop('checked',true);
  }
```

This sort of works. I get the "selectedValue" added to the < li> tag's class, but the "input" is not getting updated.

So, now a new question, **why won't the < input> tag get updated?**

Comment: Have you tried jquery filter? http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: If you loop through the entire color array, you're going to set checked on every color, but your code seems to work for just one http://jsfiddle.net/ffgx9hu2/1/

Comment: If none of the colors are visible on page load, perhaps you need to set a timeout to allow the site JS to run before you try to select the first color it makes visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @dtanders and a bunch of Googleing I finally got it to work.

```
for (var j=0; j < colorArray.length; j++){
    console.log('colorArray: ' + colorArray[j]);
    console.log('colorArray_J: ' + j);
     if(j == 0)
     {
            $('.productOptionPickListSwatch span[title="'+ colorArray[j] + '"]').closest('li').find('input.validation').click().prop('checked',true);
            $('.productOptionPickListSwatch span[title="'+ colorArray[j] + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'inline-block')
                     .first().addClass("selectedValue");
     }
     else
     {
            $('.productOptionPickListSwatch span[title="'+ colorArray[j] + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'inline-block');
     }
  }
```

This code ended up getting inserted where the swatches were being processed earlier up on the page. I did not write that code, I just stuck my changes in.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $('#about').addClass('expand');
   $(".productOptionPickListSwatch ul li[style*='inline-block']")
         .first().addClass("selectedValue")
         .find("input.validation").prop('checked',true);
});
```

[Should work](http://jsfiddle.net/21zL3vj3/)

Comment: Nope. That did not do it. No change to any of the LI tags.

Comment: Works on your sample input http://jsfiddle.net/21zL3vj3/ - so I'm guessing the live page is different.

Comment: Ok, so you are right. The code works based on what I supplied. Upon looking at the rest of the code on the page, I noticed that when viewing the source, the "style" was not appearing in the < li> tag. But when "inspecting" in Firefox, I could see that the "style" was there. So, that got me to thinking that there was some other javascript coming into play. And there is. I found where the swatch filter is happening and added part of your code to it, sort of worked.

Comment: Just made an UPDATE to the original post. Any thoughts?